# Special character in Latex

Tags: latex

I am writing a report and I need to write a "+" and "-" to be written on top of each other.Does anyone know how I can do this in Latex?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$\pm$` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using math mode:

```
$\pm$
```

Other math symbols:

http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html

Comment: Or http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to look it up by drawing a picture.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to put other things one above the other use:

```
^{x}_{y}
```

Comment: This won’t work in general. Using `\stackrel` is much better suited.

Comment: I tried it with Texify and it worked fine but i agree stackrel is better :)